# create crud doesnt work in yii2

Tags: web, frameworks, yii2, crud

i make a simple CRUD in yii2 backend from table name "Guru",i already make models with the same table and make the CRUD but when i try to Create new data from the Create function,the data doesnt saved in database at all,i already make the code similar with the frontend and change the namespace but it didnt work at all in backend.

here is my backend "Guru" models code

```
<?php 
 namespace backend\models;
 use Yii;
 class Guru extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'guru';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['nip', 'nama_guru', 'ttl', 'jenis_kelamin', 'alamat', 'telp', 'agama', 'jabatan', 'user', 'pass', 'role', 'tgl_create', 'update_create', 'mapel'], 'required'],
        [['jenis_kelamin'], 'string'],
        [['mapel'], 'integer'],
        [['nip', 'telp', 'jabatan', 'user', 'pass'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['nama_guru', 'ttl'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['alamat'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['agama', 'role', 'tgl_create', 'update_create'], 'string', 'max' => 10]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        //'id_guru' => 'Id Guru',
        'nip' => 'NIP',
        'nama_guru' => 'Nama Guru',
        'ttl' => 'Tempat Tanggal Lahir',
        'jenis_kelamin' => 'Jenis Kelamin',
        'alamat' => 'Alamat',
        'telp' => 'No Telpon',
        'agama' => 'Agama',
        'jabatan' => 'Jabatan',
        'user' => 'User',
        'pass' => 'Pass',
        'role' => 'Role',
        'tgl_create' => 'Tgl Create',
        'update_create' => 'Update Create',
        'mapel' => 'Mata Pelajaran',
    ];
}
      /**
 * @return  \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getJadwalGuru() {
    return $this->hasMany(Jadwal::className(), ['id_mapel'=>'mapel']);
}
  public function getJadwal() {
    return $this->hasMany(Jadwal::className(), ['nip'=>'id_guru']);
}
```

}

and this is my Controller code

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Guru; 
use backend\models\GuruSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;  
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Guru();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_guru]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

i really dont know why it doesnt work when the other CRUD in backend and frontend is work.i'm new to this framework,please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a validation problem, 
you have a lot of `required` field and if one is missing the model is not saved.

For evaluate this situation try using save(false ) false mean  without model validation.  in this way :

```
 public function actionCreate()
 {
    $model = new Guru();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save(false)) {
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_guru]);
    } else {
       return $this->render('create', [
           'model' => $model,
       ]);
    }
}
```

If with the param `false` the model is saved check selectively (by commenting) the rule that create problem with validation.

Comment: it works when i add "false" as a parameters,so which one should i check to know which one is not work with my code?

Comment: Well the problem is for sure inside the validation rules, could be you don't input all the required data or one of the other rules in not satisfied by your data. For my experience try commenting all (reasonabily) the rules and the one by one uncomment. so you can find the one you are looking for. If you find my suggestion usel please rate  my answer also as useful

Comment: i already found the problem,and yes there are 2 field that i missing and i already fix that...thanks bro